# ldconfig equivalent in Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, linker

Is there a parallel command to Linux's LDCONFIG for Mac OS X's Terminal?

Comment: on mac, maybe try: 'update_dyld_shared_cache'

Comment: @GalBracha Can you convert your comment to an answer ? I've just tested it and I believe it's the right answer !

Comment: @SebMa It is now an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is no.  But you can still configure the search path via environment variables, see dyld(1).

Comment: Thank you, reading the man page i saw that i needed to add an additional path to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable so that a program could find library objects i did not have the permissions required to install in their default location! I changed the ~/.tcshrc file to have the line: setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH <some other path>:{$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}  then I executed: source ~/.tcshrc  and the program found the library objects it needed.

Comment: Can anyone answer: does the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and assoc. dyld paths apply to all compilers (gcc, g++) or is this something that is clang and clang++ specific?

Comment: @phsiao you misspelled `dyld`

Answer (score 54):

Yes. Just run:

`sudo update_dyld_shared_cache`

Comment: [Manual entry](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-635.2/doc/man/man1/update_dyld_shared_cache.1.auto.html) for this command says: "Note that the new cache does not take effect until the OS is rebooted." It looks like it's not exactly a parallel thing.

Comment: This tool is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

The best suggestion I can come with is to lookup `man dyld`.

Comment: You should probably fix your $PATH, but the page is also on the Web: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html