# terminal error: cp: illegal option

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

these terminal commands are written for linux. can they be translated to mac?

```
#!/bin/sh
cp --preserve=links libleveldb.* /usr/local/lib
cp -r include/leveldb /usr/local/include/
ldconfig
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
cp: illegal option -- -
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
./try.sh: line 4: ldconfig: command not found
```

Comment: so it looks like `--preserve=links` is not a valid option for your `cp`. Check your `man cp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have `--preserve` option in Mac version of `cp`. Use `-p` option instead (see [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html))

Sometimes replacing Mac coreutils with the `GNU` ones may be a good solution. See [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities) to learn more about installing `GNU` coreutils on your Mac.

Also, the `ldconfig` won't work on Mac either. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451047/ldconfig-for-mac-os-x) to find an alternative.