# Symbol not found mac OS X

Tags: macos, boost, terminal

whenever I run "cufflinks" on the OS X terminal , I get this error:

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5boost11this_thread5hiden11sleep_untilERK8timespec

Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/cufflinks

Expected in: /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5

I tried brew upgrade and update, I also tried reinstall cufflinks , I obtained no result.
Any idea?
performing ls-l to the directory WILL return a libboost_thread-mt.dylib file amongst other files as well

-r--r--r--  1  admin    165400 Apr 17 14:18 libboost_thread-mt.dylib

Comment: Do you have a `/usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib` file? You should edit your question to improve it.

Comment: yes ls -l /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/ will return series of files  and one of them is libboost_thread-mt.dylib

Comment: As  I said, you need to *edit your question*; the comments are for others. You may want to tell the output of `ls -ls /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451047/ldconfig-for-mac-os-x is, or could be, relevant.