# z3: sudo make install fails to set up dynamic libraries on MacOS Sonoma (M1 pro)

Tags: g++, z3, dylib

I tried installing z3 compiling it from this repository (`sudo make install`) on my MacBook with M1 pro processor and MacOS Sonoma.

`make examples` worked.

I succesfully compiled a file in another directoty using the same commands used by `make examples`.

However, upon executing the compiled file, the library could not be loaded:
`Library not loaded: libz3.dylib Referenced from: <856829F0-D35A-383B-8D63-7734D9099FC4> /my_path/cpp_example Reason: tried: 'libz3.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibz3.dylib' (no such file), 'libz3.dylib' (no such file), '/my_path/libz3.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS//my_path/libz3.dylib' (no such file), '/my_path/libz3.dylib' (no such file)`

Upon forcibly copying the libz3.dylib file into the folder where the file I am trying to execute is, it worked.

Anyone has any suggestion on how to solve this problem in a more elegant way? Could it possibly be an issue with z3's make install procedure? My machine is basically empty and no weird/conflicting libraries are installed.

Thank you :)

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451047/ldconfig-equivalent-in-mac-os-x) might be helpful to update your library search path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: ..... How to correctly tell GCC Compiler where to find another static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268814/dyld-library-not-loaded-how-to-correctly-tell-gcc-compiler-where-to-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**
`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

**Ideally on linux one would do:**

`sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib`

On mac OS (sonoma) with apple silicon, forums seem to say the corresponding command is `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache`. But this seems to be deprecated.
The workaround that works for me is to export as in the TLDR.